# Customize Error Message of RequestFormLimits Attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

I am decorating a controller action in a .NET 5 app with the [RequestFormsLimits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requestformlimitsattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) attribute to restrict file size on a POST request.

Is there a way to override the error message produced by the .NET framework?

> Failed to read the request form. Multipart body length limit X
> exceeded.

Comment: You may try to add an action filter to override the error message.